# How to disable an Exchange 2007 mailbox without deleting it? Forwarding to another mailbox should not be affected

Tags: exchange-2007

What is the best-practice method for disabling an Exchange 2007 mailbox, such as after a staff member finishes a contract?

Is it enough to simply disable the user's corresponding AD account for that domain, or do additional steps (such as disabling the mailbox itself in Exchange) have to be taken?

Objectives:

- deny user access to their mailbox
- not actually delete the mailbox, as the manager or next employee may need access to existing emails in future
- allow email forwarding to the manager to be used after the mailbox is disabled (actual forwarding, rather than creating an alias)

Comment: Ok, no one here seems to know. I guess this belongs on Server Fault. You'd think with a reputation of nearly 3,000 I would have the ability to shunt my own questions into different SE sites.